# latex minted error with anaconda3 in Windows7

Tags: python, windows, latex

I have texlive 2017 installed in Windows 7.
for python, anaconda3 is installed in the system.
python path and library is known to the environment variables.

and a very simple tex file is created as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minted}[mathescape,
               linenos,
               numbersep=5pt,
               gobble=2,
               frame=lines,
               framesep=2mm]{csharp}
  string title = "This is a Unicode pi in the sky"
  /*
  Defined as $\pi=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{P_n}{d}$ where $P$ is the perimeter
  of an $n$-sided regular polygon circumscribing a
  circle of diameter $d$.
  */
  const double pi = 3.1415926535
    \end{minted}
\end{document}
```

first, open a git-bash and type the following command

```
pdflatex -shell-escape sample.tex
```

it works nice.

and then, open a cmd window and type the same command.
now, it says

```
\minted@apppathifexists=
! Package minted Error: You must have 'pygmentize' installed to use this package
```

what will be the culprit this issue?
Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48018/minted-not-working-on-mac

Comment: Finally, I resolved the problem. In PATH environment variable, C:\Windows\System32 should be included to invoke cmd.exe